# How to resolve associated models dropdown menu prob in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, formtastic

I m getting unreadable values @ dropdown menu in active admin.
I have an attribute which has a inclusion of specific values(around 10 values) but when I am making a  new object of that class by using active admin... firstly it is showing the unreadable drop down menu 
[image]
second its showing that attribute to be blank even if I m choosing some unreadable value..
[image]
 plz help

***my admin/Resident.rb page:*** :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Resident do
   permit_params :room_number,:roll_number,:name,:hostel,:hostel_id
   index do
    column :room_number
    column :roll_number
    column :name
    column :hostel
    actions
  end
  filter :name,:as => :string
  filter :hostel, :as => :select
  filter :room_number
  filter :roll_number

   form do |f|
     f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
     inputs 'Enter the student details' do
       input :room_number
       input :roll_number
       input :name
       input :hostel
       actions
     end
   end
end
```

I have two models : **Hostel** And **Resident** :
***models/hostel.rb***

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residents
end
```

***models/resident.rb***

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :hostel
  validates :room_number,presence: true,uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :roll_number,presence: true,uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false}
  validates :name, presence: true,length:{ maximum: 50 }
  validates :hostel,presence: true

  def display_name
    hostel
  end

end
```

***schema:*** :
Resident

```
create_table "residents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "room_number"
    t.string   "roll_number"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "hostel"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "hostel_id"
  end
```

Hostel:

```
create_table "hostels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "hostel"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

### end

Comment: Those are the actual objects in string representation. Depending on how you are build this drop down and what form builder you are using you will either need to supply a text and value method (:name,:id) or A hash of text to value (`{name: :id}`) or an associative Array (`[[:id:name]]`) A little bit of code would help us solve this fairly quickly

Comment: `validates :hostel,presence: true,inclusion:{in:%w(a b c h pg j frc e g i),message: "%{value} is not a valid hostel"}`
I have the above validation on my model..

Comment: `def create
    hostel = Hostel.find_by(hostel:resident_params[:hostel])
    @resident = hostel.create_resident(resident_params)  if hostel.present?
    if @user.save
        flash[:info] = "Resident Created"
      else
        flash[:info] = "Resident Creation Unsucessful"
      end
  end
`
And that's how the resident is begin created..

Comment: Please make sure in the future you add this information to your question and not the comments.

Comment: Okay ..Now whatzzz  happening here can u tell me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For making the text readable, you can reimplement the "to_s" method :

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... 
  def to_s
     self.name
  end
end
```

But active admin is smart enough to use the "name" row if existing usually. The bad side of this method is everywhere in your log etc. it will use the name. Something like `[self.id,self.name].join('-')` seems better for debugging if the name field of your table `hostels` is not unique.

Your second problem is caused by one of theses two things:

1. Check your params permits, and allow "hostel_id"
2. Ensure your `<select name="model[hostel_id]" >` and not `<select name="model[hostel]">`. This should be done automatically, if not it's probably because you didn't defined well the link `has_many / belongs_to` in your two models.

Finally, the last way is you can still push your own collection as parameter of the `f.input` into the active admin:

```
  f.input :hostel_id, collection: Hostel.all.map{|x| [x.name, x.id]}
```

One more time, this should be done automatically. In your case it's not, so look closely your db schema.

Happy Coding,

Yacine.

Comment: I have  two models : 
one is Resident and other is Hostel
Resident has attributes :hostel,name etc.
Hostel has attribute: hostel
models/Resident.rb : belongs_to:hostel
models/hostel.rb : has_many:residents
I have strong parameters method  in resident controller  and I have not allowed the hostel_id from hostel model in it..

Comment: `form do |f|
     f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
     inputs 'Enter the student details' do
       input :room_number
       input :roll_number
       input :name
       input :hostel ,:as => :check_boxes
       actions
     end
   end`
this is how my form looks like for creating a object of resident by using active admin!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def display_name
    name # or that code will return a representation of your Model instance
  end
end
```

in place of `name` use the column name whose value u want to be displayed in drop down